# Python. How to find list of line segments in giving convex_hull?

Tags: python, math, geometry

I know how to compute [convex_hull](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Geometry/Convex_hull/Monotone_chain#Python), but how to get a list of line segments creating convex_hull?

Comment: You get a list of points. Maybe you can just start a line segment at the first point, end it at the next and start a new, and so on. At the last point, reconnect with the first. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It's good clue, but I want to be sure that line segments lying on the border of polygon and not trough the "body".

Comment: Isn't that the definition of a convex hull? :)

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems like it basically explains how in the comments of the algorithm?

```
Output: a list of vertices of the convex hull in counter-clockwise order,
      starting from the vertex with the lexicographically smallest coordinates.
```

So if it does what it promises to, you can simply start with the first vertex and join it to the next one and so forth until you join the last one to the first.

You can be certain that none of the lines cross through the body since these are the vertexes that make up the convex hull and are listed in counter clockwise order.

Comment: That's the clue! Thanx :)